# CSS apply style for HTML elements on a CSS ROLE

Tags: html, css

I have an element in my HTML `<div class="TreeView"></div>` I would like apply style to tags: `td`, `div`, `table` for a specific **Class Role: TreeView**

At the moment this my code does not work.

```
td.TreeView,  div.TreeView, table.TreeView
{
    height: 20px !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The only way I'm able to make it work is: apply an ID to my div `<div id="MainContent_uxTreeView" class="TreeView"></div>` and use this css code instead:

```
    #MainContent_uxTreeView table, #MainContent_uxTreeView td, #MainContent_uxTreeView div
    {
        height: 20px !important;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

I would like not to use the second version mentioning the ID.. so what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks guys for your help!

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more code: the first works if used in a simple document, the second does not: it applies to divs/tables/cells contained in an element with the id but not to the element with the id itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to apply CSS rules for descendants of `.TreeView`:

```
.TreeView td,  .TreeView div, .TreeView table
{
    height: 20px !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector into  two css fragment you posted are slight different

```
.TreeView td,  .TreeView div, TreeView table
{
    height: 20px !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

is similar to the second one, you should try it (maybe using firebug or similar tools to 
check if the rules are somewhat overriden)

Answer (score 0):

learn some priority of ID and class and try this now

```
body td.TreeView,  body div.TreeView, body table.TreeView
{
    height: 20px !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```