# Is it possible to apply a HTML attribute to a Div Tag in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a generic DIV with a Css Role applied.

I would like to know if CSS allows to set the style for an HTML Tag inside a DIV (only for DIV with that Role) which has a Css Role.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks for your time on this.

```
   <div class="Role">
    <table></table>
    </div>

    .Role
    {
    // Style for <table> tag.
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS apply style for HTML elements on a CSS ROLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799577/css-apply-style-for-html-elements-on-a-css-role)

Comment: Thanks You for your comment, yes it is a pretty similar questions but not duplicated. In this questions I'm interested to know different methods how to do it, instead my previous questions it is more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to go:

- The *descendant selector* selector `.Role table`, for example, select for apply all the table that are contained into an element, whatever, with class Role.
- The *child selector* `.Role > table` will apply the associated rules to the tables that are child (not descendant) of the element with class Role

For example, consider this html fragment:

```
<div class="Role">
    <table id="t1">
      <tr><td>
        <table id="t2">
          ....
        </table>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

- .Role table will apply the css rule to table#t1 **and** table#t2
- .Role > table will apply the css rule to table#t1 **only**
- .Role > table table will apply the rule to table#t2 **skipping** to table#t1

Answer (score 2):

```
.role > table {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only select the `table` element if it's a direct child of `.role`.

Answer (score 2):

To style the table in div with role class you need

```
.Role table {
  //style for table tag
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible, either with a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

```
.Role table {
    // Style for <table> element.
}
```

Or with a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors):

```
.Role > table {
    // Style for <table> element.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.Role table` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just see [the CSS selectors - pattern matching](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching). You can use one of the following, depends on your needs:

```
.Role * { ... } /* matches any tag in div class="Role" */
.Role > * { ... } /* matches any tag which is direct child of div class="Role" */
```

You can replace * with any particular selector (tag, class, etc.)